# Structures inside linked lists in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I'm learning how to implement linked lists in C. I understand the basics of normal linked lists, how to add values, how to print them etc. but I've been wondering - is it possible to add other structure as a value in linked list? What I mean is:

```
typedef struct personal_info {
  char *name;
  char *surname;
  int phone_number;
} Info;

typedef struct llist {
  Info *info;
  struct llist *next;
} List;
```

And when I do this, how do I access the values of the `Info` structure?

```
List *l;
l = malloc(sizeof(List));

l->info->name = 'name';
l->info->surname = 'surname';
l->info->phone_number = 1234567890;
```

The code crashes, so I'm definitely doing something wrong. Could you give me some tips how to achieve that?

Comment: Have you allocated memory for the nodes? (The info field)

Comment: You need to allocate memory to your Info*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to allocate memory for the info struct:

```
l = malloc(sizeof(List));
l->info = malloc(sizeof(Info));

l->info->name = "name";
l->info->surname = "surname";
l->info->phone_number = 1234567890;
```

Comment: Thank you! The compiler gives me warning though: `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Comment: Use the quotation marks (`"`) for strings. Apostrophes are **incorrect**.

Comment: Ah, my bad! Another silly mistake. Coding at 2 am isn't a good idea. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
List *l;
l = malloc(sizeof(List));
l->info = malloc(sizeof(Info));
```

You have to malloc memory for the struct as well

Also remember that if you're implementing any functions that remove nodes from the list, you need to free that struct before you free the node.